# Como puedo enviar este documento pdf por correo?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Estuve realizando un documento el cual al momento de presionar un botón crea un archivo pdf descargable con el formato que le di al documento .lo que pasa es que ahora mi jefe quiere el el archivo se cree pero no para descargar sino que al momento de presionar el botón cree el pdf y lo envié vía correo electrónico a alguna de las opciones que tengo en la base de datos.
la función de crear el pdf la realice con PrintThis, no conozco muy bien esta librería y no se si puedo modificarla para que al momento de presionar el botón no me aparezca el apartado de descargar el documento sino que solo lo mande. Tenia pensado realizar al acción de enviar con PhpMail pero me gustaría saber su opinión , dejo código .

Esto es parte del documento

```
<main class="main" style="max-width: 75%;margin-left: 8%;">
    <div id="content">
      <?php
      if ($_POST) {
        $nombres = $_POST["nombres"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $apellidop = $_POST["apellidop"];
        $cemail = $_POST["cemail"];
        $apellidom = $_POST["apellidom"];

.....


echo "
        <p style='margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;font-size:21px;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:center;'>Poder simple</p>
        <p style='margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;font-size:19px;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;'>&nbsp;</p>
<p style='margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;font-size:19px;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;'>En Santiago de Chile, a $dia de  " . $mes[date('n') - 1] . " de $ano</p>


.....
<!-- El botón que crea el pdf -->

<div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="history.back()" name="volver atrás" value="Volver atrás">
      <button id="btn-print-this" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Descargar PDF</button>
    </div>
```

Ese seria el código con el que traigo el formato del pdf y con el botón creo el documento descargable

....

Con este codigo creo el descargable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-print-this').click(function(){
        $('#content').printThis();
    });
});
```

Comment: Si estás pidiendo una opinión tu pregunta seguramente terminará cerrada. (Lee [ask])

Comment: Revisé la librería, pero por lo que entendí es para imprimir, porque dices que te genera un "PDF"??

Answer (score 0):

```
//Ejemplo con formulario. Crear formulario
        <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Crear PDF dinámico y enviar adjunto por Email</h1>      
    </div>
    <?php
    if ($msgerror) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $msgerror; ?></div>
    <?php } else if ($msgsuccess) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $msgsuccess; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <div class="form"> 
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="mailto">Email A:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mailto" placeholder="Ingrese Email A" name="mailto" value="<?php echo $_POST['mailto']; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="mailfrom">Mail De:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mailfrom" placeholder="Ingrese Email De" name="mailfrom" value="<?php echo $_POST['mailfrom']; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="">Asunto Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mailsubject" placeholder="Ingrese Asunto Email" name="mailsubject" value="<?php echo $_POST['mailsubject']; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstname">Nombres:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Ingrese Nombres" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastname">Apellidos:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?>">
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="description">Descripcion:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea placeholder="Ingrese Descripcion" class="form-control" id="description"  name="description" style=" height: 268px;"><?php echo $_POST['description']; ?></textarea>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Crear y Enviar PDF</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    </div>

// LLamamos a la biblioteca para la creacion del PDF
require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');

/*Envio de email y adjunto el PDF creado*/
$mailto = $_POST['mailto'];
$mailfrom = $_POST['mailfrom'];
$mailsubject = $_POST['mailsubject'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$description = wordwrap($description, 100, "<br />");
/* rompe el contenido de la descripción cada 100 caracteres después. */

$content = '';
$content .= '
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
width:800px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
td{
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
padding: 10px; 
max-width:520px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>';

/* Tu css */
$content .= '<table>';

$content .= '<tr><td>Email A</td> <td>' . $mailto . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Mail De</td>   <td>' . $mailfrom . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Asunto Email</td>   <td>' . $mailsubject . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Nombres</td>   <td>' . $firstname . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Apellidos</td>   <td>' . $lastname . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td>Descripcion</td>   <td>' . $description . '</td> </tr>';

$content .= '</table>';

// LLmamos a la biblioteca para la creacion del PDF
require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');

// Declaramos el formato del documento PDF
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');

$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);


$to = $mailto;
$from = $mailfrom;
$subject = $mailsubject;

$message = "<p>Consulte el archivo adjunto.</p>";
$separator = md5(time());
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$filename = "pdf-documento.pdf";
$pdfdoc = $html2pdf->Output('', 'S');
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

$headers = "From: " . $from . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;

$body = '';

$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol; //had one more .$eol


$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $message . $eol;


$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $attachment . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

    $msgsuccess = 'Email enviado Correctamente';
} else {

    $msgerror = 'Email no ha sido enviado';
}

}
}
```

Comment: Gracias probare este código a ver como me va.